# Where to set tableView dataSource and delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tableView which contains cells that also have a tableView, I'm not sure how to set the datasource and delegate of the nested tableView, I've tried `cell.dataSource = self` (and for delegate) inside `cellForRow` of the main tableView, but that didn't work. Do I need an initializer in my tableView cell file of the nested cells?

[image]

Comment: Why you are using nested tableview? If you can give more detail about your desired output maybe that will lead to more good answers.

Comment: Users are able to add exercises to the table, and within each exercise they should be able to add 1-many sets to that exercise

Comment: So why are you not using group tableview with multiple sections?

Comment: mainly because I didn't know that existed until now

Comment: Ok, so you don't know about the group tableview with multiple sections?

Comment: I do now.........

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218050/discussion-between-ved-sharma-and-noah-iarrobino).

Comment: Yeah, the short answer is "don't do that." A sectioned table view is a much better way to go.

Comment: appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using nested UITableview. For the above situation, A sectioned table view is a much better way to go.